# Open, read and write files with Eclipse Milo OPC UA

Tags: eclipse, file-transfer, opc-ua, opc, milo

I always get the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" UaMethodException: status=Bad_NotFound, message=A requested item was not found or a search operation ended without success..
```

To open the file in read mode, I have to set the first bit in a byte to 1. I am unable to do this.

```
val nodeId = new NodeId(2, "Demo.Files.readwrite.txt") 

  val client: Option[OpcUaClient] = OpcConnector.createOpcClients()
  
  val objectNode = client.get.getAddressSpace.getObjectNode(nodeId)

  val x = new QualifiedName(0, "Open")

  val method = objectNode.getMethod(x)

  val b: Byte = 1
  val inputs: Array[Variant] = Array(new Variant(b))
  val outputs: Array[Variant] = method.call(inputs)
  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  logger.info("Input values: " + inputs.mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
  logger.info("Output values: " + outputs.mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
```

I tried to declare b as a byte and set b to 1 to get "00000001".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably `objectNode.getMethod(x)` that is throwing this Exception...

Are you able to get a Wireshark capture of this? Are you sure you have the right ObjectNode?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your prompt reply. 
You are right, it was the wrong ObjectNode. I have two OPC servers running.  I have been addressing the wrong server all along >.<
my code is correct (y)
But your comment pointed it out, thanks.